# OpenERP 7 Apache redirect not working

Tags: apache, redirect, odoo

Here is the situcation.

I installed OpenERP instance on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04.

Use serverip:8069 or domain-one.com:8069 to access website is no problem. Then i set up apache reverse proxy to use domain-two.com for openERP, i can't access the website. here is proxy setting:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain-two.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8069/$1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i add this to my computer /etc/hosts file:

```
serverip    domain-two.com
```

and then visit the domain-two.com, successfully visit the OpenERP instance.

domain-two nameserver setting in Route53 is correct. no problem

Where i'm doing it wrong? please help.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether your DNS setting is working fine or not using the **dig command** from linux os.

> dig domain-two.com

And then use this configurations and try again.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain-two.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

Please dont forget to restart the Apache server. Remember this configuration will not work for SSL based Proxy.

Comment: it was DNS Setting problem on domainpanel.com. SOLVED! Thanks